# どれくらいです vs どれくらいあります

Tags: word-choice

Context:

> 身長{しんちょう}はどれくらいありますか。

Why is it that ありますか is used instead of ですか？ Is there a difference or is it just interchangeable? I've searched everywhere but I am not sure what is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both grammatically different ways of asking the same thing.

身長はどれくらいですか。

About how much is your height? (Direct translation.)

身長はどれくらいありますか。

About how much is there to your height? (Direct translation.)

Though in Japanese these are grammatically different, in English, these sentences can both be translated to: "What is your approximate height?" or "About how tall are you?"